# Como fazer um cálculo em uma tabela ng2-smart-table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estou tentando fazer um calculo entre dois campos e quero mostrar o resultado em outro ao adicionar um novo item em uma tabale ng2-smart-table.

Veja como estou fazendo:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Clima } from 'src/app/model/Clima';
import { ClimaService } from 'src/app/service/clima.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import {
  SmartTableDatepickerComponent,
  SmartTableDatepickerRenderComponent,
} from 'src/app/smart-table-datepicker/smart-table-datepicker.component';
import { CustomComponent } from './custom.component';
import { LocalDataSource, ViewCell } from 'ng2-smart-table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clima',
  templateUrl: './clima.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clima.component.css'],
})
export class ClimaComponent implements OnInit {
  climas: Observable<Clima[]>;
  clima = new Clima();

  idFazenda: Number = +JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('idFazenda'));

  settings = {
    add: {
      addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-plus"></i>',
      createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
      confirmCreate: true,
    },
    edit: {
      editButtonContent: '<i class="nb-edit"></i>',
      saveButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
      confirmSave: true,
    },
    delete: {
      deleteButtonContent: '<i class="nb-trash"></i>',
      confirmDelete: true,
    },
    columns: {
      dataClima: {
        title: 'Data Clima',
        type: 'custom',
        renderComponent: SmartTableDatepickerRenderComponent,
        width: '250px',
        filter: false,
        sortDirection: 'desc',
        editor: {
          type: 'custom',
          component: SmartTableDatepickerComponent,
        },
      },
      temperaturaMaxima: {
        title: 'Temperatura Máxima',
        type: 'number',
      },
      temperaturaMinima: {
        title: 'Temperatura Mínima',
        type: 'number',
      },
      temperaturaMedia: {
        title: 'Temperatura Média',
        type: 'number',
        editor: {
          type: 'custom',
          component: CustomComponent,
          onComponentInitFunction: (instance: any) => {
            instance.save.subscribe(row => {
              //this.source.refresh();
            });
          },
        },
      },

      umidadeRelativa: {
        title: 'Umidade Relativa',
        type: 'number',
      },
      velocidadeVento: {
        title: 'Velecidade do Vento',
        type: 'number',
      },
      precipitacao: {
        title: 'Precipitação Total',
        type: 'number',
      },
      radiacaoMedia: {
        title: 'Radiação',
        type: 'number',
      },
    },
  };

  constructor(
    private climaService: ClimaService,
    private router: Router,
    private routeActive: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let idFazenda: Number = +JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('idFazenda'));
    this.climaService.getClimaListByFazenda(idFazenda).subscribe(data => {
      //this.source.load(data);
      this.climas = data;
      //this.total = data.totalElements;
    });
  }

  novo() {
    this.clima = new Clima();
  }

  excluirClima(event) {
    if (window.confirm('Tem certeza de que deseja excluir?')) {
      this.climaService.deletarClima(event.data.idClima).subscribe(data => {
        // console.log("Retorno do método delete : " + data);
        //this.culturas.splice(index, 1);/*Remover da tela*/
        // this.usuarioService.getStudentList().subscribe(data => {
        //   this.students = data;
        // });
      });
      event.confirm.resolve();
    } else {
      event.confirm.reject();
    }
  }

  salvarClima(event) {
    console.log('Edit Event In Console');
    console.log(event);
    if (
      this.clima.idClima != null &&
      this.clima.idClima.toString().trim() != null
    ) {
      /* Atualizando ou Editando*/

      console.log(this.clima);
      this.climaService.updateClima(this.clima).subscribe(data => {
        this.novo();
        this.router.navigate(['climaList']);
        console.info('Clima Atualizado: ' + data);
      });
    } else {
      event.newData.idFazenda = this.idFazenda;
      console.log('Create Event In Console');
      console.log(event);
      this.climaService.salvarClima(event.newData).subscribe(data => {
        /*Salvando um novo Clima */
        this.novo();
        console.info('Gravou Clima: ' + data);
      });
      event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);
    }
  }

  onEditConfirm(event) {
    console.log('Edit Event In Console');
    console.log(event);
    this.climaService.updateClima(event.newData).subscribe(data => {
      this.novo();
      console.info('Clima Atualizado: ' + data);
    });
    event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);
  }
}
```

Meu componente personalizado:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-component',
  template: `<td>
    <input
      [(ngModel)]="rowData.temperaturaMedia"
      (ngModelChange)="onModelChange()"
    />
  </td>`,
})
export class CustomComponent {
  rowData: any;

  @Output() save: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  onModelChange() {
    var tMaxima: number = this.rowData.temperaturaMaxima;
    var tMinima: number = this.rowData.temperaturaMinima;
    this.rowData.temperaturaMedia = (tMaxima + tMinima) / 2;
    this.save.emit(this.rowData);

    console.log(this.rowData.temperaturaMedia);
  }
}
```

Na imagem abaixo mostra que esta carregando o componente personalizado, porem não estou conseguindo calcular os campos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não seria mais simples adicionar o campo antes de renderizar com apenas um `data.map`? Assim você não precisa criar um componente customizado só pra fazer um cálculo com 2 campos

Answer (score -2):

Numa situação semelhante. Ao adicionar um novo item na table, eu fiz alguns testes e percebi que ao finalizar a adição de um item na tabela, ele chama o método salvarClima() duas vezes, ai quando eu faço um console.log() do event, vem duas vezes

Ao fazer um console.log(event) no event.newData, vem os valores duplicados

Pensei: *Como eu faço para que ele chame apenas uma vez?*

Pensando *ainda: Como eu faço para que ele calcule o total e mostre na tabela?*

Resolvi o problema da duplicação do output do evento, eu tava fazendo um `event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);` mas não deveria fazer isso, bastava fazer um `event.confirm.resolve();`
Quanto ao resultado da soma, eu não consegui fazer